# How to use ellipsis in responsive CSS table cell?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want to create something like this screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

I tried using table display when the numbers and text are table-cell and the circle is absolute position, but it seems like I can't use ellipsis on table-cell.

My design is responsive so I can't use fixed width.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yefoz02z/1/)

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="cell cell1">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="cell cell2">
        very very long text that will need to be nowrap and with ellipsis very very long text that will need to be nowrap and with ellipsis
        very very long text that will need to be nowrap and with ellipsis
        very very long text that will need to be nowrap and with ellipsis
    </div>
    <div class="cell3">
        absolute 
    </div>
</div>

.wrapper{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.cell{
    display: table-cell;
}
.cell1{
    background: yellow;
}
.cell2{
    background: lightblue;
}
```

Comment: Is the width of the table known?

Comment: No. the all page is responsive

Answer (score 4):

Because CSS ellipsis normally only works with known width container, or in a fixed table layout, I wrapped the middle cell into some divs to create another inner table for it, so it's all responsive.

For creating multiple rows, you'll need another div container and set to `display: table-row;`

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cz55qfnd/)

```css
.wrapper {
    display: table;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.row {
    display: table-row;
}
.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.cell2 .content {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
.cell2 .content .ellipsis {
    display: table-cell;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell cell1">1</div>
        <div class="cell cell2">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="ellipsis">very very long text that will need to be nowrap and with ellipsis very very long text that will need to be nowrap and with ellipsis very very long text that will need to be nowrap and with ellipsis very very long text that will need to be nowrap and with ellipsis</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cell cell3">circle</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell cell1">2</div>
        <div class="cell cell2">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="ellipsis">very very long text that will need to be nowrap and with ellipsis very very long text that will need to be nowrap and with ellipsis very very long text that will need to be nowrap and with ellipsis very very long text that will need to be nowrap and with ellipsis</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cell cell3">circle</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

I hope this is what you wanted

I've added this CSS -

```
.cell3 {
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

And this is the [**link**](https://jsfiddle.net/yefoz02z/2/) to the fiddle

**Tip:** There are better way to achieve what you're trying to achieve

Comment: My question wasn't about making a circle.

Comment: what does " I can't use ellipsis on table-cell." mean?